# What do we call "IP" and "port"?

Tags: naming, networking

When I'm looping through files and coming up with dynamically created Ansible playbooks and stuff like that, I've quite frequently had to work with a single variable that contains the IP and port of something.

Can I refer this as a "socket" or does that name always refer to a handle?

Is it better just to refer to the thing as `$ip_and_port` or `$address_and_port` or `$host_and_port`?

Comment: Answered, but this is probably a better fit for networking.so.

Comment: Also, hi Peter!

Comment: You could call it an *endpoint*.

Comment: They are of type "struct sockaddr" or more specifically "sockaddr_in" for ipv4 and "sockaddr_in6" for ipv6. So, yes, socket address.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could call it an *address* generically, or a *socket address.*

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket), "A socket address is the combination of an IP address and a port number."

Answer (score -3):

IP is actually a transport layer protocol. It assigns a unique address to your system which is referred to as IP address.

Host is a machine which provides you some services.

Port is like a door through which your system communicates to outer world.

Socket is the interface between your system and network. Just like an electrical switch. This is where your network ends and your system begins physically.

Comment: IP is a network protocol, example transport protocol would be tcp/udp.